# @ filename prefix

Tags: unix

Someone showed me how to use Quicksilver to append lines to a list and then display them on his desktop using GeekTool. I have got that all set up fine and highly recommend it...

..however whilst he was showing me I noticed that he had all the lists starting with '@' for example '@todo.txt'. I have never seen this before and was wondering whether this was a specific naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be honest, I don't think it is a standard convention. He probably just did it to quickly cancel down the list of possible files shown by quicksilver to just the lists you mentioned

Comment: thanks, didn't think anyone was going to answer this!

Comment: Same way I often name things that I want to be includes by starting them with an _, for instance _example.sh or whatever, just means that I don't see them all the time when doing tab completion in a shell, but can easily target them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @response files *is* a naming convention with (at least) Microsoft's linkers, compilers and that kind of stuff :)

It is used to place all command line options into a files instead of on the command line.

IIRC Borland C++ had (has?) this option too